# Problems incurred in an anonymous block and procedure

Tags: plsql, cursor, procedure

I was writing a code asking me to use a anonymous block to execute a procedure. And when I run the code, it shows that there are few errors. However, the error messages are not very helpful regarding what went wrong. My first question is that if I want to use a cursor inside the procedure I call in the anonymous block, should I define my cursor inside the procedure or outside the procedure but inside the anonymous block? My second question is should I keep my exception inside the cursor loop? And other than that, what went wrong with my code? Thanks.

The error report looks like this:
Error report -
ORA-06550: line 12, column 15:
PLS-00201: identifier 'ATERM' must be declared
ORA-06550: line 13, column 10:
PL/SQL: ORA-00904: : invalid identifier
ORA-06550: line 11, column 7:
PL/SQL: SQL Statement ignored
ORA-06550: line 53, column 28:
PL/SQL: ORA-00918: column ambiguously defined
ORA-06550: line 33, column 10:
PL/SQL: SQL Statement ignored
06550. 00000 -  "line %s, column %s:\n%s"
*Cause:    Usually a PL/SQL compilation error.

Answer (score 0):

dont' use INTO in the declaration cursor and move the cursor and the variables aterm, asectno, actitle, asid, afname, ascore in the lowest_score procedure.
Bye,
Igor

Comment: That is a good point. I moved my cursor into my the procedure and changed it slightly. But there are still 2 errors as follows: "Error report -
ORA-06550: line 51, column 28:
PL/SQL: ORA-00918: column ambiguously defined
ORA-06550: line 31, column 10:
PL/SQL: SQL Statement ignored
06550. 00000 -  "line %s, column %s:\n%s"
*Cause:    Usually a PL/SQL compilation error.
*Action:"

Comment: Hi, I can't see anymore code... for ORA-00918 probably you have to specify the table; for others, it seems something is missing (parentheses, semicolons, etc ). Bye, Igor